# Posting a XML with CURL is returning weird characters

Tags: xml, curl, post

I do want to monitoring a web service with CURL.

The POST works with SOAPUI:

[SoapUI output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQuIs.png)

But when I do by command line, the return is very strange:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: text/xml" --data @sku.xml http://10.107.100.36:9700/wcs/ShippingDateCalculator?wsdl
```

This is the output:

```
[root@pinche ~]# curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: text/xml" --data @sku.xml http://10.107.100.36:9700/wcs/ShippingDateCalculator?wsdl
Lo???@???????~?K?@????????~???`???onL???????zŕ??????@?????z???????~????zaa???????K???????K???a????a????????anL???????z??nL???z?????????ā??م??????@?????z???~????zaa??K?????a∉?????ā??Á????????anL????????ā???nL????????ā??nL????n??a??a????La????nL????ā?n??????La????ā?nLa????????ā??nL????????ā??nL????n??a??a????La????nL????ā?n???????La????ā?nLa????????ā??nL????????ā??nL????n??a??a????La????nL????ā?n?????La????ā?nLa????????ā??nL????????ā??nL????n??a??a????La????nL????ā?n??????La????ā?nLa????????ā??nL????????ā??nL????n??a??a????La????nL????ā?n??Q??????La????ā?nLa????????ā??nL????????ā??nL????n??a??a????La????nL????ā?n??????La????ā?nLa????????ā??nL????????ā??nL????n??a??a????La????nL????ā?n???????La????ā?nLa????????ā??nL????????ā??nL????n??a??a????La????nL????ā?n?????La????ā?nLa????????ā??nL????????ā??nL????n??a??a????La????nL????ā?n??????La????ā?nLa????????ā??nL????????ā??nL????n??a??a????La????nL????ā?n??Q??????La????ā?nLa????????ā??nLa????????ā???nL??????n??La??????nLa???z?????????ā??م??????nLa???????z??nLa???????zŕ??????n[root@pinche]#
```

[Shell output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5bho.png)

Follow the content of sku.xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ship="http://cl.hites/ShippingDateCalculator/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ship:calculateDate>
         <comuna>68</comuna>
         <skus>
            <!--1 to 20 repetitions:-->
            <sku>
               <partNumber>664860001</partNumber>
               <quantity>1</quantity>
            </sku>
         </skus>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <orderId></orderId>
      </ship:calculateDate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a hint in your first image: the server, in its `Content-Type` header, says that the content is encoded using the IBM 284 EBCDIC code page, which seems to be an ancient way of encoding Spanish-language text. Your terminal probably uses ASCII or UTF-8.

Most systems have an `iconv` command that can convert between character sets. For example, to convert IBM 284 into UTF-8:

```
curl -X POST ... | iconv -f ibm284 -t utf-8
```

Alternatively, you could of course try to figure out why the server is using EBCDIC in the first place.

Comment: Man, worked perfectly!!  Thanks to be Such a  wizard =).
I'll try to figure out, but it is probably some security standard, no?

Comment: You're welcome! Best of luck with this (I'm guessing) IBM mainframe - I don't envy you...

Comment: Nope, it's not a security standard or an encryption thing, just a [very old standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) that I don't think anybody outside IBM uses anymore.

Comment: Yah, it is a shame =( but they are the ones that pay my money, have to work with, Many thanks for the support guys!